# Must the -j argument of make be exactly the same as the number of cores?

Tags: gcc, makefile

```
 make -j$(nproc)
```

When compiling gcc from source, I saw there is a step of using -j to match the available cores. Must the argument be the same as core numbers? Does it do any harm if it is less than actual core numbers? For example, if I have 8 cores, but I use:

```
make -j 4
```

Any consequences?

Comment: `-j` sets the number of processes to use to compile your code. If you use less, it compiles slower.

Comment: I see. So it doesn't mean the compiled gcc can only use the number of cores configured here. Right? Slow compiling is fine.

Comment: `So it doesn't mean the compiled gcc can only use the number of cores configured here.` No. It has no effect on the result at all.

Comment: That's very nice.

Comment: To be exact, gcc does not use multiple cores at all. It's the `make` that spawns that many compiler instances to compile multiple files at the same time. You can use any value you want (or even no value to spawn as many tasks as possible), but a reasonable value would be number of cores so that you utilize all CPU power without overloading the system.